# Django DateField cannot be None

Tags: python, sql, django

I'm really struggeling wih the DateTime cannot be None Issue of Django (3.0.4).

I Know this is a known Issue on Stackoverflow but I'm not able to solve it.

I do have the Field:

```
begin_holidays = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

And now if a submit a form where request.POST['begin_holidays'] is not set I get the error:

```
„“ is invalid date format. It has to be YYYY-MM-DD
```

Has anyone an Idea ?

Comment: Can you spefy the `ModelForm` you use?

Comment: Im not using a ModelFom im getting the data from request.POST

Comment: well then it makes perfect sense that it is not working, since an empty string is indeed not valid to assign to a `DateField`, you should pass it a `None` instead. But this is exactly *why* you better use a `ModelForm`.

Comment: I get your Poit but even if I set the Field to None I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you leave it blank, it will submit the empty string, hence that will not work.

You can try to assign this:

```
myobject.begin_holidays = request.POST['begin_holidays'] or None
```

But I strongly advise to make use of [*modelforms* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/) instead. Since this will automatically do the cleaning, validation, and remove a lot of boilerplate code.

Comment: But isnt tha the same as request.POST.get('begin_holidays',None) ?

Comment: @phwebn: no, since the `request.POST`, based on your input contains a value: the empty string. The `or` evaluates the truthiness of the left operand, and if it is falsely (for example the empty string), then it takes the right operand.